# Bootstrap - Centering input text box

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to center an input box on the center of the page. When you click the button "Prices" It should show a text box right under the button centered. Instead, it's showing all the way to the left.

Here is what I have:

```
<div class="header-content">
  <div class="header-content-inner">

    <h1 class="text text-primary vintage-retro sr-intro">IFixIT Repair</h1>
    <hr class ="sr-intro">
    <p style="font-family:Arial;" class ="text sr-intro">Repairs By Students, For Students</p>
    <a href='#repair' class="btn btn-primary btn-xl page-scroll sr-intro btn-margin-head">Schedule Repair</a>
  </div>

  <a href="#repair-prices" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl sr-intro btn-margin-head" data-toggle="collapse">Prices</a>
  <div id="repair-prices" class="text-center collapse">
    <input class="typeahead form-control" name="search" placeholder="Model of Device (i.e. iPhone 6)">
  </div>

</div>
```

With this, I get this result after the button click:
[The box is all the way to the left.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0Guy.jpg)

Any help would be awesome! If you need to see anything else, let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `<center>` tag, that may help.
If you are using HTML5, this does not work and you must center using CSS.

Comment: Html5 use `text-align: center` in css

Comment: <center> tag is not supported in **html5**. use **css** instead

Answer (score 0):

Try using add some css in input class. Because when you used `form-control` class it has `display:block` property, so that it will take 100% of width.

```css
.typeahead.form-control{
  display:inline-block;
  width:auto;
  min-width:280px;
}
.btn.btn-primary.sr-intro{
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="header-content text-center">
  <div class="header-content-inner ">
    <h1 class="text text-primary vintage-retro sr-intro">IFixIT Repair</h1>
    <hr class ="sr-intro">
    <p style="font-family:Arial;" class ="text sr-intro">Repairs By Students, For Students</p>
    <a href='#repair' class="btn btn-primary btn-xl page-scroll sr-intro btn-margin-head">Schedule Repair</a>
  </div>

  <a href="#repair-prices" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl sr-intro btn-margin-head" data-toggle="collapse">Prices</a>
  <div id="repair-prices" class="text-center">
    <input class="typeahead form-control" name="search" placeholder="Model of Device (i.e. iPhone 6)">
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether is correct, but i have tried your code with fiddle

[>>> fiddle demo <<<](https://fiddle.jshell.net/kinggeneral/5gvno6ax/) without form-control class

add this and remove form-control class

```
.text-center {
    text-align: center;
}
```

your form-control class in search is 100% width, so you cant center it.